# How to update my record value sql in webservice

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I already have my table like this
[Picture Table Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dncg.png)
This is my coding for add new user in webservice

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void AddNewUser(String jsonOfDataUser)
    {
        DbAccessConnection conn = getActiveConnection();

        if (conn == null)
            return;

        try
        {
            beginTransaction(conn);

            Testing test = new Testing(conn);
            User users = Tools.convertJsonIncludeDerivedTypes<User>(jsonOfDataUser);

            test.add(users);

            commitTransaction(conn);
            Responder.writeResponse(true, "Success Add New User");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            rollbackTransaction(conn);
            Responder.writeResponse(false, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }


    public void add(User dtUser)
    {
        String sql = $"INSERT INTO testing(id,email,name) 
        VALUES('{dtUser.Id}','{dtUser.Email}','{dtUser.Name}')";
        Connection.executeSql(sql);
    }
```

This is my coding for update in webservice

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void UpdateUser(String jsonOfData)
    {
        DbAccessConnection conn = getActiveConnection();

        if (conn == null)
            return;

        try
        {
            beginTransaction(conn);

            Testing test = new Testing(conn);
            User users = Tools.convertJsonIncludeDerivedTypes<User>(jsonOfData);

            test.update(users);

            commitTransaction(conn);
            Responder.writeResponse(true, "Success Update New User ");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            rollbackTransaction(conn);
            Responder.writeResponse(false, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }

   public void update(User dtUser)
   {
        String sql = $"UPDATE INTO testing(id,email,name,profile_image) 
        VALUES('{dtUser.Id}','{dtUser.Email}','{dtUser.Name}','{dtUser.Profile_Image}' 
        WHERE id = '{dtUser.Id}')";
        Connection.executeSql(sql);
    }
```

I got problem execute method UpdateUser in webservice, my record table cannot update in database when i insert json

```
{"Id":"00001","Name":"testing","Email":"testing@gmail.com","Profile_Image":"C:\image\iconaudit.jpg"}
```

Could you help me, how to fix it ?

Comment: where is dtGoogle object in your update scope

Comment: sorry, i already change it is object dtUser

Comment: ID is a primary Key. that is a value that should be automatically given and only be given by teh DB. | You problem description is thus far "Does not work". What exactly is happening or not happening?

Comment: I give id is primary key maybe I should change it instead of the primary key, and exactly not happening when i execute data json with profile_image in method UpdateUser

Comment: You do not insert ot update the Primary Key, ever. The PK is something the DBMS and only the DBMS manages. You always use the PK in the where condition for Updates and Deletes. Because without something as solid as the PK to limit them, they will ruin your DB. | Als you still ahve not told us what the issue is. What is the exception? What is happening or not happening?

Comment: @Christopher PK can updatable if it's not identity

Comment: @ReyhanManuel whats your exception message

Comment: I want insert file path to field Profile_Image to my table testing in database using method UpdateUser, so when i execute method UpdateUser in webservice my field will update field, so last field in table testing id = 00001, email = testing@gmail.com, name = testing, profile_image = C:\image\iconaudit.jpg

Comment: it is my message error                               {"isSuccess":false,"resultMessage":"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO testing(id,email,name,profile_image) VALUES('00001','testing' at line 1","data":"

Comment: @erdiyılmaz If a value can be changed by the user, it is not a usefull or valid PK. At best it opens the PK up to race conditons wich ruins data integrity. Wich is one of the primary concerns of Databases. | PrimaryKeys must always be unique, and DBMS created/managed. Ideally also part of a Index, but that is optional outside of perforamnce. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key

Comment: @ReyhanManuel remove into after update  UPDATE testing(id,email,name,profile_image)...

Comment: @erdiyılmaz  i try remove into when running in webservice i got message error {"isSuccess":false,"resultMessage":"After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered

Comment: @erdiyılmaz it is success adding in my database, just now i forget insert 
quotation mark, Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO testing(id,email,name,profile_image) VALUES('00001','testing' at line 1","data":

That is plain and simple not how you write a Update statement:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

`INTO` and `VALUES` apply to `INSERT` and only `INSERT` statements.

Also to reiterate, the `ID` column should be the primary key. And those you do not set and should never update either. You use them to constrain updates and deletes. Because without a `WHERE` those would always modify your entire table. And nothing is as good a identifier as the PK.

Limiting updates and deletes is basically what primary keys have been *invented* for. Some other uses (synchronisation of a distributed database) might apply, but even there it acts the same way.